# Get rid of UoW's implicitness

Tags: nhibernate, entity-framework

NHibernate's Session and EF's ObjectContext are implementations of Unit of Work pattern and suggest similar approaches for change tracking: you retrieve some entities, then modify them somehow and after that call SaveChanges/SubmitChanges/Save/etc.

I don't like the implicitness of this approach. I don't like that entity modification automatically means it will be saved. I would like to explicitly mark entities that should be saved. What are the best ways to achieve this kind of control in NHibernate or EF?

Comment: What is the reason for you to change entities when you don't want to change them anyway?

Comment: For example, user has modified several entities in user interface of desktop application and before saving decided to cancel his modifications to one of entities. Or I could just want to modify some properties for UI display reasons.

Comment: What you want goes against the idea of a the unit of work pattern. I think you should separate the entities in their own unit of work.

Comment: But it makes it very and very difficult to implement change tracking

Comment: What's hard about using change tracking when you use multiple UoWs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(note: fortunately I've never dealt with EF; my answer is about NH only)
I think your initial assumption is wrong:

> entity modification automatically
>   means it will be saved

that's not true; in order to persist the changes you've made you need to either:

1. call Session.Flush() yourself
2. set Session's flush mode to AutoCommit (highly not recommended)
3. use an ITransaction and commit it (by far the best approach).

unless you do any of the above your changes would not be persisted.
Personally I feel that NH gives me complete control over what goes into my DB.

[here'](http://nhforge.org/wikis/patternsandpractices/nhibernate-and-the-unit-of-work-pattern.aspx)s a good article.

Comment: By "automatically" I meant automatically during UoW saving (aka Session flushing), as you described

Comment: @Idsa: so I'm guessing your problem is that things like `session.Flush()` flush *all* the changes to the db and not just the ones you want? If so- using transactions can help you control that. this is one of the reasons why explicit usage of transactions is preferred over Flush.